# Image alignment using HTML TextFlow

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm using a TextArea control with an HTML based textflow and can't seem to work out how to align the images.

HTML:

```
<p><img src='assets/images/pic.png' width='32' height='32'/>Some text. </p>
```

Import to text flow:

```
myText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(content, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

The problem is the text doesn't align around the image, it always sits underneath, i need the top of the image to align with the text. I checked the TextConverter documentation and it says that it doesn't support align in the img tag.

[I'm trying to achieve something like this...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c2028ff4112df207af8b-8000.html)

But i need the text to be in an .xml file, not hardcoded into the component. I've been looking into it for a while and can't seem to find an answer, it doesn't need to be HTML necessarily, i just need to be able to manage the formatting and text using an external file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is of any use to anyone, but to align the top of the image with the text within a single line you can use the property `dominantBaseLine` of the textFlow and `lineHeight` of the specific InlineGraphicElement (or img). Set `dominantBaseLine='ideographicCenter'` and set `lineHeight='[enter desired height here]'` in the xml. If you don't set `lineHeight` it will overlap any lines below. I haven't figured out how to let TextFlow solve this automatically.

If you want to be able to use images of variable height... well, I abused the InlineGraphicElement `styleName` property as a tag to get these images using TextFlow's `getElementsByStyleName()` and then setting the InlineGraphicElement's `lineHeight` within the code. It's not pretty but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try these: width='30' height='30' align='left' hspace='10' vspace='10'